# Get previous paths from ReactRouter.browserHistory

Tags: react-router

Is it possible to get the previous number of paths and the path values from `ReactRouter.browserHistory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't.
But you can try storing a list in `browserHistory` state and pushing new path in it when you redirect.

```js
let history = this.props.location.state.history;
history.push(this.props.location.pathname)
browserHistory.push({
    pathname: '/yourpath',
    state: { history: history }
})
```

in this way you should find all your history in `this.props.location.state.history`

Comment: Thanks, I actually had to do this in `componentWillUpdate` of a route that always renders at path match of `/`, I would compare `location.key`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is unpredictable when using Ionic + React, at least for me. I always get that the router length is always greater than `1` when navigating, even if it `IS` the first page being rendered. I am trying to `exit` the app when the user clicks the `back button` and this was the first view when the app was first rendered